# hide propery in nested self refenced entity in API Platform v3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have a self referenced entity where the `$children` property shows me which are the children of a specific category. But that property is also present for each `$parent` (and also children's children).

Is it possible to hide the `$children` for every nested relation, but show it for requested resource?

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(normalizationContext: ["groups" => ["category", "category_item"]]),
        new GetCollection(),
    ]
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Category
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Category::class)]
    #[Groups(["category_item"])]
    private $parent;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Category::class, mappedBy: "parent")]
    #[Groups(["category_item"])]
    private $children;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Groups(["category"])]
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setParent(Category $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Sample data

| ID | parent | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | root |
| 2 | 1 | child-1 |
| 3 | 1 | child-2 |
| 4 | 1 | child-3 |
| 5 | 2 | child-1-1 |
| 6 | 2 | child-1-2 |
| 7 | 5 | child-1-1-1 |
| 8 | 7 | child-1-1-1-1 |

If I do a `GET` request to `/categories/5`, I get this response

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Category",
    "@id": "/categories/5",
    "@type": "Category",
    "parent": {
        "@id": "/categories/2",
        "@type": "Category",
        "parent": {
            "@id": "/categories/1",
            "@type": "Category",
            "children": [
                "/categories/2",
                {
                    "@id": "/categories/3",
                    "@type": "Category",
                    "parent": "/categories/1",
                    "children": [],
                    "name": "child-2"
                },
                {
                    "@id": "/categories/4",
                    "@type": "Category",
                    "parent": "/categories/1",
                    "children": [],
                    "name": "child-3"
                }
            ],
            "name": "root"
        },
        "children": [
            "/categories/5",
            {
                "@id": "/categories/6",
                "@type": "Category",
                "parent": "/categories/2",
                "children": [],
                "name": "child-1-2"
            }
        ],
        "name": "child-1"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "@id": "/categories/7",
            "@type": "Category",
            "parent": "/categories/5",
            "children": [
                {
                    "@id": "/categories/8",
                    "@type": "Category",
                    "parent": "/categories/7",
                    "children": [],
                    "name": "child-1-1-1-1"
                }
            ],
            "name": "child-1-1-1"
        }
    ],
    "name": "child-1-1"
}
```

I would like to get a reponse like this where `children` is missing in every `parent`

```
{
    "@context": "/contexts/Category",
    "@id": "/categories/5",
    "@type": "Category",
    "parent": {
        "@id": "/categories/2",
        "@type": "Category",
        "parent": {
            "@id": "/categories/1",
            "@type": "Category",
            "name": "root"
        },
        "name": "child-1"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "@id": "/categories/7",
            "@type": "Category",
            "parent": "/categories/5",
            "name": "child-1-1-1"
        }
    ],
    "name": "child-1-1"
}
```

I've tryied using `maxdepth` annotation and it works for children's children (note the missing child-1-1-1-1 in the example above). But I need the parents to have no children at all.

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Category::class, mappedBy: "parent")]
#[Groups(["category_item"])]
#[MaxDepth(1)]
private $children;
```